# Customized color palette in seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following correlation matrix 'corr' drawn using the following commands:

```
import seaborn as sns; 
sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax = sns.heatmap(corr, annot=True, fmt="0.2f", linewidths=.5)
```

[image]

Is there a way to create a color palette which is symmetric around 0. With greenish tones around 0, and reddish tones when approaching +1 or -1, if this is possible. In this way, green (or cold colors) means 'no correlation', and red (warm colors) means 'high correlation' (either positive or negative).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list) can be used. To have the green exactly in the center, `vmin` and `vmax` need to be set symmetric to zero.

```py
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

corr = np.corrcoef(np.random.random(((5, 5))))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('RedGreenRed', ['crimson', 'lime', 'crimson'])
ax = sns.heatmap(corr, cmap=cmap, vmin=-1, vmax=1, annot=True, fmt="0.2f", linewidths=.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Adding a yellowish color halfway between red and green could look nicer: `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['crimson', 'gold', 'lime', 'gold', 'crimson'])`